# Porting code from C#.net to C++ MFC - Loading DLL issue - EntryPoint index

Tags: c#, visual-c++, dllimport

I need to do the same as the C# .net code below in C++ MFC
can you guys help me out?

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("shell32.dll", EntryPoint = "#261",
            CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, PreserveSig = false)]
        public static extern void GetUserTilePath(
          string username, 
          UInt32 whatever, // 0x80000000
          StringBuilder picpath, int maxLength);

        public static string GetUserTilePath(string username)
        {   // username: use null for current user
            var sb = new StringBuilder(1000);
            GetUserTilePath(username, 0x80000000, sb, sb.Capacity);
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path =GetUserTilePath(null);
            Console.WriteLine("path = %s", path);
        }
    }
}
```

I cant get to the GetProcAddress from the #261 (or 261) entry point and/or its exactly signature to C++.

EDIT: Here is the Trick

```
HMODULE shell32Dll= ::LoadLibrary(L"shell32.dll");


HRESULT (__stdcall *getUserImage)(LPCWSTR userName,
                        DWORD zero , LPWSTR outPath, UINT size);

(FARPROC&)getUserImage = ::GetProcAddress(shell32Dll, MAKEINTRESOURCEA(261));
if(getUserImage)
{
        WCHAR outPath[MAX_PATH];
        getUserImage(NULL,0x80000000,outPath,MAX_PATH);
}
```

MAKEINTRESOURCEA(261) instead of "#261" or "261" make get the job done!

Thank you! Cameron!

Comment: What error did you get? What OS you are using?

Comment: Win 7 and 8 are the target SO.
i get Null from GetProcAddress

Comment: can you show your c++ code that is failing

Comment: Why not just link against shell32 directly?

Comment: @Cameron not sure if i understood you. Can you share an example?

Comment: @Carlos: Instead of loading the DLL manually at run time, why not link against it at compile time (in fact, you probably already are by default)? Then you can just include the header and use the GetUserTilePath function directly -- *goes and checks which header* Oh. It turns out this is an as-yet undocumented function. So using LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress is the only way to get at this function for now. Never mind! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [GetProcAddr documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> lpProcName [in]
>   The function or variable name, or the function's ordinal value. **If this parameter is an ordinal value, it must be in the low-order word**; the high-order word must be zero.

It turns out you should be calling it like so:

```
(FARPROC&)getUserImage = ::GetProcAddress(shell32Dll, MAKEINTRESOURCE(261));
```

Comment: 'GetProcAddress' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'int' to 'LPCSTR'
If you mean (FARPROC&)getUserImage = ::GetProcAddress(shell32Dll, "261");
It still returns null;

Comment: @Carlos_rpg: Yep, sorry about that. See my edit. I meant (LPCSTR)261, but there's actually a macro which exists for this purpose.

Comment: Thank You! 
(FARPROC&)getUserImage = ::GetProcAddress(shell32Dll, MAKEINTRESOURCEA(261)); Worked! (just modify MAKEINTRESOURCE to MAKEINTRESOURCEA)

Comment: @Carlos_rpg: Great! I'm not sure why MAKEINTRESOURCE wasn't #defined to MAKEINTRESOURCEA, but oh well. If you switch to Unicode later you'll need to change it to MAKEINTRESOURCEW to match GetProcAddress under _UNICODE.